# Inno setup. Modify txt file befor install

Tags: file, text

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall
I am using that link.

How to induce prodedure?

```
procedure MyBeforeInstall2(wirtie.txt: some text);
begin
MsgBox('About to install ' + FileName + ' as ' + CurrentFileName + '.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

And how to repair it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you want to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to delete/add some text/delete some text. From text file, before insatll

Comment: Using inno setup, or any tool to create instaler.

Comment: I don"t know how to start :(

Comment: SaveStringToFile('write.txt', #13#10 + 'the string' + #13#10, True);

Comment: Doesn"t working

Comment: It created new text file in output folder.

Comment: If you want to put a fixed text into your installer, why don't you put a fixed file in there?